# OData, EFCore DTO Error: Expression 'Example.DTOs.Models.ProcessDTO' in the SQL tree does not have a type mapping assigned

Tags: entity-framework-core, odata, automapper, entity, dto

**What I´m trying to do**:

I have an ASP.NET Core project with an ODataController. The ODataController returns DTOs and recevies ODataQueryOptions of type DTO. With Automapper included I can cast my Query from DTO Query to Entity Query to query the DBContext Entities as follows

```
_dbContext.TimeSheets.GetQuery(_mapper, request.Options)
```

**What going wrong**

Everything works fine if I only use $count, $filter,... But when I´m using $expand it fails.
I have two cases

1. I´m trying to expand a single property: The query is operated and in my result-view I can see that the property is expanded and also of type DTO but when the service returns it back to the client I get the Error *Expression 'Example.DTOs.Models.ProcessDTO' in the SQL tree does not have a type mapping assigned*
2. I´m trying to expand a property of type ICollection: The query is operated but in my result-view I cannot see the expanded property. When the service returns it back to the client I get the Error *System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : ODataResourceSerializer cannot write an object of type 'Collection(Example.DTOs.Interfaces.ITimeSheetDTO)'*

**What is attached**

Git-Repo: [OData_EF_Automapper.git](https://github.com/MasterFlu/OData_EF_Automapper.git)
Info: The Project is separated into 6 project.

1. Example.CQRS: Here are the Queries and handlers used for the MediatR
2. **Example.DTOs**: Here are the DTOs defined which are used by the client and for the ODataQueryOptions
3. Example.Entities: Here are the Entites used by EF Core. There is also a ready to use database and the OData/EdmModelOData for defining the EDM. ***This is an important file to look at***
4. Example.Mappers: Here are all Profiles defined used by AutoMapper
5. Example.Server: Here are the ODataControllers defined. **ProcessODataController and TimeSheetODataController are important for this problem**
6. Example.Tests: Here are the UnitTests to test the ODataController. **The two test files ODataProcessTests and ODataTimesheetTests are relevant to reproduce the error!**

=> Please use the Test **ODataTimesheetTests/Get_Timesheets_To_Process_One** to reproduce **Error 1**

=> Please use the Test **ODataProcessTests/Get_Process_One_With_Timesheets** to reproduce **Error 2**

Hope this is all you need and thank you for your support.

---

## SOLUTION

For everyone running into this error I post the solution I grabbed from different blog posts and forums.

I have added a class that solves the query for me:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using Microsoft.OData.UriParser;

namespace Hsetu.TimeSheet.CQRS.QueryHelpers
{
  public class QuerySolver<TEntity, TDTO>
  {
     private readonly ODataQueryOptions<TDTO> _options;
     private readonly IMapper _mapper;

     public QuerySolver(ODataQueryOptions<TDTO> options, IMapper mapper) 
     {
        _options = options;
        _mapper = mapper;
  }

  public async Task<IQueryable<TDTO>> Solve(IQueryable<TEntity> dataSource)
  {
     var edmModel = _options.Context.Model;
     var edmEntitySet = edmModel.FindDeclaredEntitySet(typeof(TEntity).Name);

     var context = new ODataQueryContext(edmModel, typeof(TEntity), _options.Context.Path);
     var edmType = context.ElementType;

     var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.RawValues.Filter))
     {
        parameters.Add("$filter", _options.RawValues.Filter);
     }

     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.RawValues.Expand))
     {
        parameters.Add("$expand", _options.RawValues.Expand);
     }

     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.RawValues.OrderBy))
     {
        parameters.Add("$orderby", _options.RawValues.OrderBy);
     }

     var parser = new ODataQueryOptionParser(edmModel, edmType, edmEntitySet, parameters);

     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.RawValues.Filter))
     {
        var filter = new FilterQueryOption(_options.RawValues.Filter, context, parser);
        dataSource = (IQueryable<TEntity>)filter.ApplyTo(dataSource, new ODataQuerySettings());
     }

     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.RawValues.OrderBy))
     {
        var orderBy = new OrderByQueryOption(_options.RawValues.OrderBy, context, parser);
        dataSource = orderBy.ApplyTo(dataSource, new ODataQuerySettings());
     }

     IQueryable<object> expandableQueryable = null;

     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.RawValues.Expand))
     {
        var expand = new SelectExpandQueryOption(null, _options.RawValues.Expand, context, parser);
        expandableQueryable = (IQueryable<object>)expand.ApplyTo(dataSource, new ODataQuerySettings());
     }

     int pageIndex = 1;
     var hasPageIndex = _options.Request.Query.TryGetValue("$pageindex", out StringValues pageIndexRaw);

     if (hasPageIndex)
     {
        var isTrue = int.TryParse(pageIndexRaw, out int _pageIndexRaw);
        pageIndex = (isTrue && _pageIndexRaw > 0) ? _pageIndexRaw : pageIndex;
     }

     int? pageSize = null;
     var hasPageSize = _options.Request.Query.TryGetValue("$pagesize", out StringValues pageSizeRaw);

     if (hasPageSize)
     {
        var isTrue = int.TryParse(pageSizeRaw, out int _pageSizeRaw);
        pageSize = (isTrue && _pageSizeRaw > 0) ? _pageSizeRaw : null;
     }

     IQueryable<object> queryToExecute = expandableQueryable ?? (IQueryable<object>)dataSource;

     List<object>? records;

     if(hasPageIndex && pageSize.HasValue)
     {
        records = await queryToExecute.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize.Value).Take(pageSize.Value).ToListAsync();
     }
     else if (hasPageIndex && !pageSize.HasValue)
     {
        records = await queryToExecute.Skip((pageIndex - 1)).ToListAsync();
     }
     else if (!hasPageIndex && pageSize.HasValue)
     {
        records = await queryToExecute.Take(pageSize.Value).ToListAsync();
     }
     else
     {
        records = await queryToExecute.ToListAsync();
     }

     //var count = await queryToExecute.CountAsync();

     var result = MapDomain(records).ToList();

     return _mapper.Map<List<TDTO>>(result).AsQueryable();
  }

  private IEnumerable<TEntity> MapDomain(IEnumerable<object> objs)
  {
     List<TEntity> resultList = new List<TEntity>();

     foreach (var item in objs)
     {
        if (item is TEntity)
        {
           resultList.Add((TEntity)item);
        }
        else if (item.GetType().Name == "SelectAllAndExpand`1")
        {
           var entityProperty = item.GetType().GetProperty("Instance");

           if (entityProperty != null)
           {
              var val = entityProperty.GetValue(item);

              if (val != null && (TEntity)val != null)
              {
                 var castedObj = (TEntity)val;
                 resultList.Add(castedObj);
              }
           }
        }
     }

     return resultList;
  } // https://www.jauernig-it.de/intercepting-and-post-processing-odata-queries-on-the-server/
  }
}
```

And in your controller or handler call it like this:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<ProcessDTO>> Handle(GetProcessesQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   QuerySolver<Process, ProcessDTO> solver = new QuerySolver<Process, ProcessDTO>(request.Options, _mapper);
   var result = await solver.Solve(_dbContext.Processes);
   return result;
}
```

Or with nested expand for example $expand=timeSheets($select=name) do sth. like this:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<TimeSheetDTO>> Handle(GetTimeSheetsQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   var query = await _dbContext.Processes.GetQueryAsync(_mapper, request.Options);
   QuerySolver<TimeSheetDTO, TimeSheetDTO> solver = new QuerySolver<TimeSheetDTO, TimeSheetDTO>(request.Options, _mapper);
   var result = await solver.Solve(query);
   return result;
}
```